# How to create sample T3 Purity3 site

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

What I need to do:
Create a sample site using T3 Purity3 template that looks exactly like this:
http://purity_iii.demo.joomlart.com/index.php/layout/new-layouts/blog

What I did so far:

- First I installed Joomla localy via XAMPP, then installed T3 Framework via extension manager, then installed Purity3 via extension manager.
- Then I created few sample articles with random words inside to work with.
- Then I changed site layout and menu layout to blog.

This should be enough but sadly it looks nothing like the demo. My articles aren't expendable but spread whole page long one above another. I don't have right sidebar Blog Tags, Chronology nor Categories. I don't even have page changer below articles that spread new articles between multiple pages (pushing old ones firther). Basically instead of demo clone I have one big nothing.

Also I can't find any reliable tutorial on how to make this on my own. JA tutorial which i found there:
http://www.joomlart.com/documentation/purity-iii/layout-in-details#default-layout

Is worth nothing because:

1. I don't know where to find half the menu's they mention here, and
   obviously tutorial don't mention it,
2. Screenshots are from linux version or stylized to look like so
       which destroys all readability,

In the end what I need is to make sample blog fast and easy. That's why I installed Joomla and Purity3 in first place. Good guide (self made or link to one) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than manually installing Joomla, then the T3 framework and then the template, I would strongly suggest you use the Quick Start package which contains everything in 1 bundle.

When installing it asks you if you would like to install any sample data, there should be a custom option that will set up all articles and extensions that you see on the demo site.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Simultaneous, identical answers after 2 hours. What are the odds? lol

Comment: erm....erm...great minds think alike :)

Comment: Oh... right... that's what I thought too

Comment: Actually the problem is I want to know/learn how this things are done. And to be honest I don't feel pro enough to learn it by reverse engineering. So far I managed to collapse articles, but the main issue still stands: I don't know how to fill the empty boxes with all those things like TAG-menu, Archive-menu, etc. not to mention filling page head with one big image as it is done in most sites these days or just styling buttons and titles. Anyway thanks for answer guys - one thing You cleared out is installing quickstart - I was doing it the wrong way.

Comment: @NecXelos - The best thing to do would be to check out the demo page for the template and see what module position are available. That's mainly what your see on demo sites. If you also look at the quickstart package, you can actually see how JoomlArt have actually composed their pages 1 by 1 ;)

Comment: I did check it and I found few things but this opened a way for even more questions: how is some of the styling done? It's like positions not modules are styled... Is it possible that in the end I need to dig into the code anyway? I did some temporary changes with Firefox tools but that's probably a stupid way to get things done?

Comment: Could you explain with an example of even screenshot of what you mean please?

Comment: I believe I don't have permission to post images yet. But I believe that I can explain it. Quickstart example vs My example. Quickstart example main page is this big blue "Hello I'm Purity" thing. It has blue background. It is custom html module with text. No background specified. When I did the same thing I get the text allright but there is no "normal" way to edit the background to be as blue as menu. On the other hand I found via Firefox tools place in CSS where this blue background is specified (only in their example - in my own I had to write this line myself).

Comment: That's just one example of many other things like changing main menu height, styling positions (not modules that land inside them) or just adding my own boxes etc. It's like in their Quickstart example they not only used their template but also wrote dozens of css lines from scratch. Unless I'm missing some options that allow me to stylize and organize everything in normal (GUI) way. If You know the way to do things I mentioned above I'll gladly take it :) If not - is it safe'n'sane to just locate css files with Fox tools and monkey-change them?

Answer (score 1):

You should download and install the [quickstart package](https://www.joomlart.com/documentation/purity-iii/installation-and-folder-structure#quickstart). It's a zip-file containing an exact copy of the demo site, including both Joomla, the Purity III template and any extension used in the demo.

You should be able to download the quickstart package here: http://www.joomlart.com/forums/downloads.php?do=cat&id=519

Note that this is not to be installed from the Joomla extension manager. You install it like you install Joomla (unzip to a subfolder of your your XAMPP `htdocs` folder, visit http://localhost/yoursubfolder and follow the instructions. More details can be found at the [Purity III documentation site](https://www.joomlart.com/documentation/purity-iii/installation-and-folder-structure#quickstart).

Once installed, you can either build your site using the demo, or use the demo as reference for your own site to see exactly how each part is set up.